# How to make a specific div do something?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="gethover"></div>
    <div class="gethover"></div>
    <div class="gethover"></div>
    <div class="gethover"></div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

hey guys I just want to one of these div to get hover when the mouse get on that...I just mean that when we hover one of these the other ones do not get hover... how should I do it?

Comment: Do...what, exactly? You can use the psuedo class `:hover` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp but what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I understand you want to give same `class` names but you want to keep different css `hover` features for them. You can use this selectors

```css
.gethover:first-of-type:hover {
  background: red;
}
.gethover:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  background: blue;
}
.gethover:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="gethover">1</div>
    <div class="gethover">2</div>
    <div class="gethover">3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is not very detailed, if this answer cannot answer what you are trying to ask, please inform us so we can help you.

However, if you want to make hover effect, you can use :hover

```
gethover:hover{
   // attributes...
}
```

If you want to implement a js code on hover, you can achive this by

```
onmouseover="doSth()"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a specific div react on a hover just at `:hover` to the css selector. e.g.

**your.css**

```css
.gethover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.gethover:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

To see it working add some content to the div. e.g.

```html
<div class="gethover">ONE</div>
<div class="gethover">TWO</div>
<div class="gethover">THREE</div>
<div class="gethover">FOUR</div>
```

Check more on the hover selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)